# Cross compiling gcc 7.2 from x86_64 to aarch64

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, arm64, gcc7

I have successfully compiled gcc 7.2 from source on an x86_64. Native to native, so the resulting compiler is an x86_64 binary which works fine.

I would also like to have a working compiler for aarch64 (so, not a cross compiler. An aarch64 compiler binary producing aarch64 results.) This is where I'm stuck.

There's two options, a native-to-native compilation of gcc on the aarch64 host. This causes problems, and on top, is slow as mollasses, or a cross compilation of gcc on x86_64, resulting in an aarch64 compiler binary able to produce other aarch64 binaries.

I downloaded and unpacked gcc 7.2, and did the `download_prerequisites` step. Then I used the following `configure`:

```
../gcc-7.2.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu \
--target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-7.2 \
--enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib \
--program-suffix=-7.2
```

I suspect the `--build`, `--host` and `--target` are overkill in the native case, though.
My question is now, what should I set these three to if I want to end up with the aarch64 compiler?

Down the line, I would also like an armv7l version. What would be the options for this?

Comment: What you want to build (build=x86_64, host=aarch64, target=aarch64) is known as a Canadian Cross Compiler, and is notoriously tricky to put together. A full native (build=aarch64, host=aarch64, target=aarch64) compiler is much easier. You say this causes many problems, but I haven't encountered these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Didn't know about the Canadian Cross Compiler. The reason why the native aarch64 build causes problems for me is a combination of permissions and execution speed/storage on the aarch64 machines, but I'll give that path another go.

Comment: You can set the prefix to any directory (outside of the source tree), which should help with your permissions problems. i.e. `--prefix=/path/you/can/write/to` . There's nothing I can do to boost the execution speed of your platform, but depending on how well-checked you need your compiler to be, you can skip bootstrap by configuring with `--disable-bootstrap` - that will cut the build time significantly.

Comment: I'm now trying to build directly on the arm machine (a DragonBoard running Debian 9) and I'm encountering what looks to me like memory exhaustion.

Comment: That sounds a bit like this GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81818 which has caused trouble for others trying to build on platforms with 1GB system memory.

Comment: Just add some more swap, I built GCC 7.2 on a Raspberry Pi Zero (512MB), never a problem.  The configure line for aarch64 (obviously for a cortex-a53 target) is ."./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-cpu=cortex-a53" which works perfectly - built on the SBC itself.